# Timer, UpdatePanel and dynamically created buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an update panel with a div (with runat="server") so I dynamically create and add buttons to it on a timer tick event.

The problem is that when a button is click, the is a postback but the button is gone and the event is not raised.

Here's my aspx page and my c# code behind. Nothing I write in the btn1_click actually occurs.

There's a continue to my question but in order to keep it simple, I would like to understand the above first.

I really need your help and i appreciate it, ty.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
    </asp:Timer>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div id="div2" runat="server">div2</div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and this c# here.

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            }

            protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CreateControl();
            }

            void CreateControl()
            {
                Button btn1 = new Button();
                btn1.ID = "btn1";
                btn1.Text = "click me";
                btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
                div1.Controls.Add(btn1);
            }

            void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                div1.InnerHtml += "btn1 was clicked";
            }



        }
```

Comment: could you post your actual code or something close to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically added controls you must add them in every page load event. Otherwise by the time it gets to the click event the are already gone. In this case I would add the button to a session collection of buttons every time you create one, then reload that entire collection on every postback, so it doesn't lose what you've already added. Also, save an int in session that you increment so they dont all have the same ID. IDs should be unique

something like:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          if(Page.IsPostBack)
           {
             CreateControls(YourCollectionInSession)
           }
        }
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateControl();
        }
 void CreateControl()
        {
            Button btn1 = new Button();
            btn1.ID = "btn" + yourSessionID;
            btn1.Text = "click me";
            btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
            div1.Controls.Add(btn1);
            yourSessionID++;
            YourCollectionInSession.Add(btn1);
        }
 void CreateControl(List<Button> buttons)
        {
            foreach(Button btn in buttons)
            {
            div1.Controls.Add(btn); 
            }
        }
```

I've had to do the same thing before and this approach worked for me. Just remember the [ASPx Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx). It will always hit the page_init and page_load before it handles any post back events, meaning your controls are long gone.

Comment: First,thank you.

on my real application on the timer event I create controls according to changing data in the database (kind of online users list).

I must add the without the update panel I can successfully make the button work well as I do recreate it every postback.

The problem is that I need the button inside the update panel so every interval there will be an up to date list of buttons, without causing a whole page ugly post back.

The problem is even more complicated as I need the button that is clicked to load data into another update panel, again without causing an ugly post back.

Comment: Is there anyway you can post your actual code, or at least something more accurate to it?

Comment: but what i want to do .. that i need to update my online users every 30 sec without post back.  the timer event to create controls according to changing data in the database ((( without  postback ))) .. if someone go offline delete him from page if someone go online add him in the page automaticly without postback.